# Continue the java code at catching the exception

Tags: java

I am writing a java program for parsing an `XML` file and detecting if its `UTF-8` compliant. I've gotten that part working but when it catches the first exception (syntax error) it stops the execution. I want it to find all the errors and not just the first one. Is there any way I can log the errors and not stop it on the first one? Here's my code.

```
 import java.io.IOException;
 import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
 import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
 import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
 import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
 import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

  //import com.edankert.SimpleErrorHandler;
 public abstract class Wellformed extends DocumentBuilder {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
         try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
             factory.setValidating(false);
             factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

               DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
               builder.setErrorHandler(new SimpleErrorHandler());

               builder.parse(new InputSource("contacts.xml"));
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SAXException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
          }

        }
      }

    import org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler;
    import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;

      public class SimpleErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

       public void warning(SAXParseException e) {
      }

          public void error(SAXParseException e) {
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
         }

          public void fatalError(SAXParseException e) {
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
         }
     }
```

Comment: exceptions aren't syntax errors

Comment: Usually one syntax error confuses the parser completely, so it may generate dozens or hundreds of subsequent error messages which all are consequences of the first error. Thus it may not make much sense to try to get all errors from a given run.

Comment: Java does not have the ability to "resume at point of exception" -- you must resume following the catch block.  But presumably there is a diagnostic mode in any reasonably well designed parser that will signal the errors as events or place them in a log, vs throwing exceptions.

Comment: Try using an IDE that provides some sort of built in error checking.

Comment: Is there any way to just log the particular error and cancel out the line with first error and continue parsing through the rest of the file?

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own [ErrorHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ErrorHandler.html) that does not throw and attach that to `builder` (instead of the `SimpleErrorHandler`)

Comment: How can I catch the error then?(I mean without using SAXParseException )

Comment: Also tried write my own ErrorHandler instead of SimpleErrorHandler. But it didnt let me implement ErrorHandler class without throwing those exceptions.

Comment: @user1466695 - do you mean without declaring those exceptions on the method?  If so, you arenot obligated to throw those exceptions (the `throws` clause indicates what _can_ be thrown)

Comment: import org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;

public class MoreSimple implements ErrorHandler {

    public void warning(SAXParseException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    public void error(SAXParseException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    public void fatalError(SAXParseException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

Comment: @user1466695 - do you still get exceptions in the `main` block with this `MoreSimple` error handler?

Comment: I am confused on how am I going to prevent it from using try n catch block even if I make a new class. Because I'll have to still implement ErrorHandler to detect the errors?

Comment: public abstract class Wellformed extends DocumentBuilder {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
      
        
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setValidating(false);
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
             builder.setErrorHandler(new MoreSimple());

            builder.parse(new InputSource("contacts.xml"));
        
         
        
      
      }
}

Comment: @user1466695 - you cannot do away with the `catch` block if that's what you are after -- after all the compiler cannot know that `parse` will not throw an exception (and it might throw an `IOException` anyway reardless of the error handler).  [cont.]

Comment: [cont.] The documentation of `ErrorHandler` states this: "Note, however, that there is no requirement that the parser continue to report additional errors after a call to fatalError. In other words, a SAX driver class may throw an exception after reporting any fatalError. Also parsers may throw appropriate exceptions for non-XML errors. For example, XMLReader.parse() would throw an IOException for errors accessing entities or the document."   Which means you might get an exception for fatal errors even if the error handler swallows them

Comment: so you mean I should keep just SAXException and IOException?

Comment: Is there any way to just log the particular error and cancel out the line with first error and continue parsing through the rest of the file?

Comment: @user1466695 - your `MoreSimple` handler should print out all errors the parser encounters.  Not sure what you mean by "Cancel out the line"

Comment: How can MoreSimple print all the errors? I mean its exactly as the Simple ErrorHandler is.What else do I need to change in main or MoreSimple?

Comment: public class MoreSimple implements ErrorHandler {

    public void warning(SAXParseException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    public void error(SAXParseException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    public void fatalError(SAXParseException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

Comment: @user1466695 - that error handler will print all errors the parser hands to it, which is what I understood you wanted.  As long as the parser itself does not throw an exception, the parsing will continue (with a bunch of errors sent to the error handler).  There is no way to get rid of the catch blocks in your `main()` (which seems to have been another thing you wanted)

Comment: So I just change the name from SimpleErrorHandler to MoreSimple? I tried with that and it does the same thing as before. Dont know how just changing the name of the class is gona change anything

Comment: @user1466695 - I wasn't sure what the `SimpleErrorHandler` was doing exactly (thought it was a thrird party code), that's why I suggested to use a new one with known body.  If they are achieving the same result you can use either (the change of name itself does nothing).  I'm still in the dark what _exactly_ your problem is: you seem to be getting the errors printed (and unless the parser throws, all errors should be printed, not just the first) -- isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: I am not getting all the errors printed. I am just getting the first error printed. It stops the execution after it hits the first error. Thats what I am trying to reolve.

Comment: @user1466695 - I see -- the problem (I think -- can't be sure without the exact exception+stack trace) is that the parser is throwing an error (as is allowed to do according to the above quote from the error handler) on a fatal error.  You will either have to implement your own `DocumentBuilder` or find an implementation/library that can continue even on a fatal error.  I don't think I will be able to help you here